# Using a GPU's USB-C output to connect to a docking station

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, gpu, docking-station

I have a dual-screen setup for my desktop, one is HDMI, and the other is DP.

Both are hooked up to my GPU with the appropriate cables. I also have a Thinkpad (my work laptop), which I connect to a dual screen at the office through a USB-C dock.

I would like to be able to work from home using both my (external) screens for my laptop. Given my GPU (RTX 2070) has a USB-C output, I was wondering if I could buy a Thinkpad USB-C dock (with HDMI/DP outputs), hook up my screens/peripherals to it, and just swap the usb-c cable from my laptop to desktop (GPU) when I want to switch from one to the other.

My understanding is that this should work, but I might have bandwidth issues depending on the screens I use since the data transfer would happen through a USB 3.1 Gen 2 lane, which has a limit of 10GBps. If that just results in limiting my res/freq to 1080p60hz for 2 screens then it's not a big deal.

Does anyone know if this would indeed work?

Comment: USB data bandwidth is (mostly) unrelated to DisplayPort data transmission over USB-C. // Check whether the USB-C port on your graphics card supports the required features.

Comment: which features should I be looking for ? The port itself is VirtualLink, which from what I'm seeing can function as a standard USB lane, though it also has extra DP lanes, I don't really understand what will be used when I connect a dock to it

Answer (score 0):

That should work but I'd suggest checking the GPU, drivers, and whatever else is in the chain, for support for MST.  MST, or multi-stream transport, is an optional part of the DisplayPort specification that allows for support of more than one display on a single connection.

The USB-C specification allows for a number of different video protocols to be carried but it would be rare to see anything other than DisplayPort video from a USB-C port.  Again it is important to check more than just if the USB-C port supports MST on DisplayPort as there could be something else preventing a dock splitting out MST streams to two displays such as a drive limitation.

I'll suggest an alternative solution that may be cheaper and easier.  Consider daisy-chaining the displays by DisplayPort MST.  If both displays support DisplayPort, and one of them has an output for DisplayPort MST, then consider connecting the second display to the first by DisplayPort, then the first display to the computer by a USB-C to DisplayPort cable.  This makes it possible to switch the displays from one computer to another by moving the cable from the USB-C port on one to the other.

If the desire for a dock is to supply power to the laptop then doing as I suggest might not be desirable.  Some displays will allow for using USB-C cables to supply power and a DisplayPort connection, some not.  If using a USB-C cable as input to the display then if there is a DisplayPort output for daisy-chaining displays then it should still operate as it would if using a DisplayPort input.

This gets confusing because there is the physical ports and the protocols that can have the same or similar names, I hope I'm being clear in spite of this.  There is a DisplayPort port that will often carry the DisplayPort protocol but not always, it might use the HDMI protocol.  USB-C ports can carry a number of protocols, the DisplayPort protocol is one of them.  If everything is using DisplayPort with MST then you should be able to get what you want one way or another.  Using a dock should do fine, I simply offer an alternative of daisy-chaining as that might be cheaper, easier, and "cleaner" than using a dock.